# Cannot convert assembleRelease to a task

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to publish my library with below Gradle DSL:

```
publications {
    prodRelease(MavenPublication) {
        groupId appGroupId
        artifactId appReleaseArtifactId
        version libVersion
        artifact("${defaultOutputTargetDir}${outputFileNameRelease}"){
            builtBy('assembleRelease')
        }
        ext.repoType = 'Prod'
    }
}
```

While trying to publish, I always get an error:

```
> Cannot convert assembleRelease to a task.
The following types/formats are supported:
- A Task instance
- A Buildable instance
- A TaskDependency instance
- A Provider that represents a task output
- A Provider instance that returns any of these types
- A Closure instance that returns any of these types
- A Callable instance that returns any of these types
- An Iterable, Collection, Map or array instance that contains any of these types
```

What could be wrong here? Moreover, this started happening when I upgraded my Gradle from 4.6 to 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

`builtBy` requires an object so you cannot simply pass a `String` there. Try this instead:

```kotlin
artifact("${defaultOutputTargetDir}${outputFileNameRelease}") {
    builtBy(tasks.getByName("assemble"))
}
```

Note: This code is using the Kotlin DSL, not Groovy.

For Groovy you can use:

```
artifact("${defaultOutputTargetDir}${outputFileNameRelease}") {
    builtBy assembleRelease
}
```